# how to filter only user Spring beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am using

```
context.getBeanDefinitionNames()
```

for listing all beans loaded, but, how can I filter this list to show only beans defined by user/programmer? I don't want to see all beans that are instantiated automatically by Spring Framework.

Comment: thanks for editing @davioooh

Answer (score 5):

- Loop over the beanDefinitionNames
- for each name get the bean using context.getBean(name)
- filter out those, where bean.getClass().getPackage() does not start with org.spring